# How to hide my name in Whatsapp group?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, privacy

I've provided a screenshot, clickable for full size, of a group I'm in. Some people are able to hide their names. How can I do it? I do not know some people in the group and I don't want them contacting me.

[image: whatsapp group]

Comment: Why don't you enter a blank Unicode character? Like this:

Comment: Use no-break space from here: https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html

Answer (score 1):

Well you cannot hide names in WhatsApp at all. As you know it wont accept a blank as profile name.

1.Coming to the blank names beside the contact number is shown because the other person has saved you in his contact but his number is not saved(with a name) in your contacts list. Due to this the app will show only the contact number but not the name.

**Update-**  Try saving the contact with a name and then refresh your contacts in whats app for this first force stop the app then clear the cache (this works most of the time irrespective of the make or mode of internet )

2.You may be using an older version of the application.(you have not specified the version so it can also be the problem).

3.You could be blocked by the other person so you cannot see his name initially(later last seen and then the display pic)

If the above still do not solve your problem then try reading the [faq 1](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/20970403) and [faq 2](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/general/23740821)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I always keep the app up to date. So 2nd is ruled out. And I'm also sure that they haven't blocked me because they have no reason to do so. I haven't even met some of those people in my life and I haven't texted them. So 3rd also not possible. I'm not sure about the 1st. Why will so many random people save my number all of a sudden?

Comment: In the first there's also a refresh your contacts

Comment: check the update for the 1st option

Comment: When I enter some random name, the random name is shown now in the group.

Comment: exactly that's what you have already agreed. Did you refresh your contacts list and followd the update

Comment: Yep. Also, i deleted the contact and refreshed. Now again the name is gone. Just the number is shown in the group.

Comment: mind if you can leave your complete step by step guide in the enthusiasts chat with @myname your situation is kind off unique

Comment: I don't have enough rep to chat. I think it's possible to keep name empty using samsung devices. Just guessing. Because one of the person hiding his name is using a samsung phone I heard. I don't want to start asking this complete stranger how he does that.

Comment: ok I will ask it in chat then

Comment: And I just deleted my friend's contact and refreshed. I'm sure he has saved my number. Now his name is shown in the group. Not just the number. So, your 1st point also not correct I think.

Comment: @Srikaanth thats what my 1st point is you cannot hide your name in whats app you will get the name

Comment: I'm using Whatsapp+. Maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, its a hack for WhatsApp. I should say that it is a bug in WhatsApp that if you copy this ⇨ ຸ from here and paste in place of your name or about and then delete the ⇨ then tap save, then you name or about will not show. There would be empty spaces instead.
WhatsApp, on its official website (FAQs), says that status can't be empty but you can using this trick. So it's a loophole actually.
For status, if it doesn't go empty by that trick, just try to paste the ⇨ ຸ and delete both the characters, i.e.,  ⇨ as well as  ຸ and then save to see if it works.
But if you are a professional, you might want strangers to recognise you right away.